# Multi Region Active Active Replication with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-kinesis

We have a requirement of multi region active-active replication of our web-services. Primarily I am trying to replicate all the data required for billing (request, response) and analysis.

So far I have seen the following aws tools.

1. Push all data to individual SQS in different regions, then to DynamoDBs. DynamoDB will sync data automatically, then consume from DynamoDB.
2. Use separate SNS for each region, then push data to SQS ( SNS pushes data to SQS residing in different regions), and finally consume data from SQS
3. Update SQS in different regions, read this data using lambda function. Lambda functions send data to SNS in different regions, get data from SNS

is there any other tools I can use to achieve active-active architecture?
I had a look at kinesis, but not sure if its suitable for my requirement.

Anyone has any views on the proposed architectures?

Comment: There are several pieces of information that would be relevant for anyone trying to answer your question. What sort of queries do you need to perform? What is the lifecycle of your data? What sort of latency is acceptable when trying to retrieve your data?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinvent anything here - DynamoDB already supports [cross-region replication with multi-master writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GlobalTables.html) - it's called "Global Tables".

Comment: Thanks! I have already explored global tables, but the size of data I have is huge and little concerned about the cost too.

Comment: While cost can be an issue, make sure you're  accounting for proper cost of alternatives including development & maintenance of that custom solution, and costs related to trade-offs in terms of reliability

Comment: If you're concerned about cost, you could always use S3. It's about the cheapest you can get for storage, but whether you can use it depends on the sort of queries you need to perform on your data.

Answer (score 0):

For Item 3, instead of writing your own Lambda, you can use Amazon SNS to fan out messages to multi SQS queues, even in multiple different regions.  Details here: [Sending Amazon SNS messages to an Amazon SQS queue or AWS Lambda function in a different Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-cross-region-delivery.html)